# Error loading JEDI components in Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.2.3

Tags: delphi, rad-studio, jedi

We are a long-time Delphi shop, and are in the process of porting a legacy Delphi application to web.  Delphi 10.2.3 has been running fine until just a few days ago when, I am guessing, a Windows update broke my environment.  I am unable to roll back to before the Windows Update.  This is a Windows 11 workstation.

Now when loading RAD Studio, I am receiving the following error:

> Registration procedure, Jvcorereg.Register in package C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl\JvCoreDesign250.bpl raised exception class EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 5003946D in module 'borlndmm.dll'. Read of address 00200064.

Does anyone have any idea how to correct this issue?

We are using JEDI Code Library 2.8.0.5677 and JEDI VCL 3.5.  We can't really update to a newer version of JEDI because we have several custom components which extend these JEDI components, and the developer that created those components is no longer with us.

Can anyone please help?  If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue to this, I believe I had to run it in compatibility mode to fix the issue until I could reinstall the drivers (although not exactly the same). It does seem like either drivers or JEDI need updating but may be worth trying compatibility mode if that is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I just tried it with in compatibility mode for both Windows 8 and Windows 7.  Windows 8 did NOT work, but it appears that Window 7 mode is letting me in.  Thank you very much.